# Create additional entities when entity is created in Symfony 2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to initialize a new user after she is created by creating additional related entities, e.g. create banking accounts to store his funds in different currencies.

I've tried to use Doctrine Entity Listeners for this and `postPersist` event, which looked exactly what I was looking for, but after hours of extremely strange behavior (persistance exceptions and duplicate records) I've read that it's not advised to issue another `flush()` from the doctrine event handlers.

How do I approach this problem? I know I can use some external queue system to register and process events via background workers, but it looks like a way to complex scenario for my use case.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just create the related objects in the constructor? Doctrine will persist them recursively, iirc.

Comment: You want create an aggregate root (#DDD)

Comment: Could you exlain this sentence `I want to initialize a new user after she is created by creating additional related entities` a bit further? It's hard to understand, for me at least.

Comment: @KhorneHoly `User` entity has a collection of `Account[]`. I want to create new account entities for new user when she's created automatically, because each user must have three accounts.

Comment: @Pete the logic for account creation is contained in a service, to which user entity has no access, because user is a POPO.

Comment: @SlavaFominII Passing those three Account objects to the constructor is not an option? If those three Accounts are  _required_ to create a valid User object, you should pass them to the constructor to avoid the creation of invalid objects.

Comment: @Pete I'm with you here. You shouldn't be able to construct a new user without those three accounts. You must extend your registration process therefore that the user must create those three accounts before he can create a valid user.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion. However, passing all related entities to `User` constructor will make it cumbersome and difficult to use. I was hoping to implement more *magical* approach.

Comment: @Federkun thanks. But, could you explain, please, how this pattern could be applied to my use case?

Comment: Instead of a Doctrine event, emit a Symfony registration event and have your listener add the necessary additional objects.  On the other hand, if every new user is required to have three accounts then make a user factory to create your user.  Try to keep it as simple as possible,

Comment: Thank you @Cerad I'm looking into user factory approach right now. From where do you suggest to emit the Symfony event? If I emit it from Doctrine entity listener wouldn't I fall into the same trap of forbidden `flush()`?

Comment: I avoid Doctrine events.  Emit a Symfony event after creating your user object.  But again, if a user is required to have three accounts to be valid then do yourself a favor and create them all at the same time.  No need for fragile events at all.  And persisting an invalid user with the intention of fixing it later is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

You are possibly looking for the `postFlush` event?

See: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postflush

```
function postFlush($args) {
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    foreach ($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            // check for existing accounts, etc.
            // create new, if needed
            // $em->persist($account);
        }
    }
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: postFlush is called at the end of EntityManager#flush(). EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside its listeners.